# HTML Form passing two deminsion array to PHP (special case i think)

Tags: php, html, forms, multidimensional-array

This HTML code

```
<input name="Html_Array[][title]">
<input name="Html_Array[][amount]">
```

Generate this PHP Array

```
    [0] => Array
            (
                [title] => Seilpendel für Tragsysteme
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 2
            )...So on
```

**What will be HTML code to Generate following PHP Array**

```
        [0] => Array
            (
                [title] => Seilpendel für Tragsysteme
                [amount] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [title] => Article Tiel
                [amount] => 2
            )
```

Size of array is unknown so we can't hard-code index to 0,1,2 etc

Comment: Does you HTML page generated automatically? You will have to use similar to <input name="Html_Array[0]]['title']" >

Comment: *"Size of array is unknown so we can't hard-code index to 0,1,2 etc"* So how are you creating the unknown number of input elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep an index every time you add a new group of form fields (uses jQuery):

```
window.count = 0;
$('#add-more-button').on('click', function() {
 $('<input name="html_array[' + window.count + '][title] />').appendTo('form:first');
 $('<input name="html_array[' + window.count + '][amount] />').appendTo('form:first');
 window.count++;
});
```

You should get the right structure.

**Edit** if you mean PHP:

```
// Assuming 0-indexed array
foreach($my_array as $key => $value) {
 echo '<input name="html_array[' . $key . '][title]" />';
 echo '<input name="html_array[' . $key . '][value]" />';
}
```

Comment: good solution but already have it. need answer in HTML instead of javascript or jquery

Comment: @Wasim: The key idea here is to use `[0]`, `[1]` etc instead of `[]`. @tomhallam: The idea is right, but the OP does not indicate he is using jQuery at all. I don't think the code will be helpful in any way.

Comment: Well yes, you'll need to have `<input name="html_array[0][title]" /> .... <input name="html_array[34][title]" />` to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can create that exact structure in HTML. Just merge them:

```
$result = array();
$current = array();

foreach($input as $item) {
    $k = reset(keys($item));

    if(isset($current[$k])) {
        $result[] = $current;
        $current = array();
    }

    $current[$item] = $item[$k];
}
```

Comment: @Wasim: *Ahem* "I don't think you can create that exact structure in HTML."

Comment: @Wasim then why are you tagging your question as PHP?

Comment: its html,php and array problem, so php tag was neccassary

Answer (score 1):

```
 <input name="Html_Array[0][title]">
 <input name="Html_Array[0][amount]">

 <input name="Html_Array[1][title]">
 <input name="Html_Array[1][amount]">
```

and so on...

a loop can be used to generate the integer sequence needed.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the quotation marks that wrapped the second dimension array name

```
 <input name="Html_Array[][title]">
 <input name="Html_Array[][amount]">
```

Comment: thanks to make correction in question. but problem was some thing else